# Showing blank page in WebView in no Internet Connected

Tags: android

In my WebView show URL Address when Mobile User doesn't have an Internet connection.
So, I would like to show White Screen when user in WebView activity with no Internet connection.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

First you should network connection programatically.

If network connection is not available simply navigate to another activity or set another layout to your current activity.